# change xml attributes based on condition via XSLT

Tags: xslt

Can any one  help in transforming  my xml though XSLT.
I am new to this xslt and could not able to make it work.

Here is  sample  input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
  <BOMLine bl_appearance_path_node="" bl_attachments="#id13 #id15 #id20 #id21 #id22 #id3" bl_bomview="" bl_bomview_rev="" bl_gde_bomview_rev="" bl_item="#id7" bl_real_occurrence="" bl_revision="#id8" elemId="id61">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id2" label="_RnrSUKuM1CaiD"/>

</BOMLine>
 <DrawingSheet creation_date="2012-06-05T09:27:19Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id69" format_used="BINARY" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:27:20Z" license_list="" object_desc="" object_name="Sheet 1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id24" label="RoL9sTu6BT4jNA"/>

</DrawingSheet>
  <DrawingSheet creation_date="2012-06-05T09:28:44Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id70" format_used="BINARY" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:28:45Z" license_list="" object_desc="" object_name="Sheet 1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id25" label="RoO9sTvgBT4jNA"/>

</DrawingSheet>
  <DrawingSheet creation_date="2012-06-05T09:29:29Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id71" format_used="BINARY" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:29:29Z" license_list="" object_desc="" object_name="Sheet 1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id26" label="RoO9sTfVBT4jNA"/>

</DrawingSheet>
 <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id78" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id21" secondary_object="#id25" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id50" label="R8D9sTvgBT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id79" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id22" secondary_object="#id26" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id56" label="R8D9sTfVBT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id80" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id20" secondary_object="#id24" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id44" label="R8A9sTu6BT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
<UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:25:34Z" license_list="" object_desc="dwg3" object_name="dwg3" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="RXM9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
  <UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id118" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" license_list="" object_desc="dwg1" object_name="dwg1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id20" label="R3K9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
  <UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:28Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id119" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:25:34Z" license_list="" object_desc="dwg2" object_name="dwg2" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id22" label="xuO9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
</TCXML>
```

In this xml file there are 3 IMAN_Drawing ,3 Drawing Sheet and 3 UGPART tags.
For example ,

```
<IMAN_Drawing elemId="id78" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id21" secondary_object="#id25" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id50" label="R8D9sTvgBT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
```

So i want to copy UGPART's (primary_object id21 in this case) object_name and append to DrawingSheet's (secondary_object id25 in this case) object_name. So finally DrawingSheet name will be UGPART's object_name _ DrawingSheet's object_name.
For this case DrawingSheet object_name willget updated as dwg3_Sheet 1

So finally i want output xml for my input.xml as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
  <BOMLine bl_appearance_path_node="" bl_attachments="#id13 #id15 #id20 #id21 #id22 #id3" bl_bomview="" bl_bomview_rev="" bl_gde_bomview_rev="" bl_item="#id7" bl_real_occurrence="" bl_revision="#id8" elemId="id61">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id2" label="_RnrSUKuM1CaiD"/>

</BOMLine>
 <DrawingSheet creation_date="2012-06-05T09:27:19Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id69" format_used="BINARY" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:27:20Z" license_list="" object_desc="" object_name="dwg1_Sheet 1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id24" label="RoL9sTu6BT4jNA"/>

</DrawingSheet>
  <DrawingSheet creation_date="2012-06-05T09:28:44Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id70" format_used="BINARY" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:28:45Z" license_list="" object_desc="" object_name="dwg3_Sheet 1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id25" label="RoO9sTvgBT4jNA"/>

</DrawingSheet>
  <DrawingSheet creation_date="2012-06-05T09:29:29Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id71" format_used="BINARY" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:29:29Z" license_list="" object_desc="" object_name="dwg2_Sheet 1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id26" label="RoO9sTfVBT4jNA"/>

</DrawingSheet>
 <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id78" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id21" secondary_object="#id25" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id50" label="R8D9sTvgBT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id79" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id22" secondary_object="#id26" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id56" label="R8D9sTfVBT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id80" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id20" secondary_object="#id24" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id44" label="R8A9sTu6BT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
<UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:25:34Z" license_list="" object_desc="dwg3" object_name="dwg3" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="RXM9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
  <UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id118" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" license_list="" object_desc="dwg1" object_name="dwg1" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id20" label="R3K9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
  <UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:28Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id119" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" highest_rev_prop="1" ip_classification="" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-06-05T09:25:34Z" license_list="" object_desc="dwg2" object_name="dwg2" owning_organization="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id22" label="xuO9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
</TCXML>
```

I am looking for  xslt 1.0 solution.

This is my xslt (i was trying to update UGPART attribute by passing value through parameter but it is going as empty value) with which i was trying but somehow it is not working. As i was not able  to update attribute for  UGPART i did not tried to update DrawingSheet name which is that i want to update.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:plm="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing">  
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing">
        <xsl:variable name="currentSecObjectId" select="@secondary_object"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RefSecObjectId" select="substring($currentSecObjectId,2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentPrimaryObjectId" select="/plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing/@primary_object"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RefPrimaryObjectId" select="substring($currentPrimaryObjectId,2)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="UGPart">
            <xsl:with-param name="PriId" select="$RefPrimaryObjectId"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:apply-templates/>  

</xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="/plm:TCXML/plm:UGPART" name="UGPart">
    <xsl:param name="PriId"/>
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="@object_name="'Test'">
        <xsl:attribute name="owning_organization">
            <xsl:value-of select="$PriId"/>
        </xsl:attribute>        
    </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='owning_organization')]" /> 
    <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. People are very likely to help you, but not do the task in its entirety. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: There is something amiss here. You say you want DrawingSheet/@object_name to be a function of UGPART nodes, but there is no clear link between the two.

Comment: @Parag, could edit the input and output documents, cutting them down to show the absolute minimum needed to illustrate your problem. The samples are needlessly complicated so we cant see the wood for the trees.

Comment: @Durkin - As i explained for one sample after my sample input file  IMAN_Drawing is the realtion which will tell us from which UGPART object name to be  added to which Drawing sheet.primary_object in this realtion points to id21 (id21 is gsidentity elemId of UGPART) and secondary_object in this relation points to id25 (id25 is gsidentity elemId of DrawingSheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following pattern, really light and clean:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template to copy input xml as is --> 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- specific template to update just DrawingSheet -->
    <xsl:template match="DrawingSheet">

        <!-- get UPGART id from IMAN_Drawing -->
        <!-- get UPGART object_name -->
        <!-- update Drawing Sheet obejct_name -->

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly followign xslt worked for my question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:plm="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- This is general rule to copy every thing that we dont specify condition-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="plm:IMAN_Drawing">
    <xsl:variable name="Pri_id" select="substring(@primary_object,2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="Sec_id" select="substring(@secondary_object,2)" />
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 


        <xsl:for-each select="../plm:UGPART[plm:GSIdentity/@elemId=$Pri_id]">
            <xsl:variable name="UGpartName" select="@object_name"/>
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>                      
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="DrawingSheet">
                <xsl:with-param name="Sec_ID_For_Drawing" select="$Sec_id"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="UGPART_Name" select="$UGpartName"/>   
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="plm:UGPART"/>
<xsl:template match="plm:DrawingSheet"/>
<xsl:template match="plm:DrawingSheet" name ="DrawingSheet">
<xsl:param name="Sec_ID_For_Drawing"/>
<xsl:param name="UGPART_Name"/>
<xsl:for-each select="../plm:DrawingSheet[plm:GSIdentity/@elemId=$Sec_ID_For_Drawing]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="DarwingObjectName" select="@object_name"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="object_name">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($UGPART_Name,'_',$DarwingObjectName)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks everyone who helped me. Thanks Sean . B Durkin

Answer (score 0):

Parag, congratulations on a good self-answer!

Although this may not be any better, for your interest, here is another solution from a different perspective. Building on Empo's solution, it takes a functional view, asking the question, what is the output expressed as a function of input, rather than a procedural (for-each, call-template etc.) view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:plm="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="plm:DrawingSheet">
 <xsl:variable name="Sec_Id" select="plm:GSIdentity/@elemId" />
 <xsl:variable name="Pri_id" select="
    substring(
       ../plm:IMAN_Drawing[$Sec_Id=substring(@secondary_object,2)]
       /@primary_object,2)" />
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:attribute name="object_name">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(
        ../plm:UGPART[plm:GSIdentity/@elemId=$Pri_id]/@object_name,
       '_',
       @object_name)" /> 
   </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Sean , this is very good solution. I will use this one.